# visual code : remove comment from json file

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am exporting a huge documents collection from mongo using robo 3t, and the export is like :

```
/* 1 */
{
"key":"value"
}
/* 2 */
{
"key":"value"
}
...
/* 2456 */
{
"key":"value"
}
```

I need to remove all the lines like /* X */ where X is the number. I am using the replace file method in vscode, but I can't put a valid regex to match all thoses lines : this is what I am puting in the search textbox : `/* (.*?)`

thanks in advance

Comment: `*` is a special character in `regex`, it means the previous expression repeated zero or more times. In order to represent itself, it needs to be escaped with ``\``.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a special character in `regex`, it means the previous expression repeated zero or more times. In order to represent itself, it needs to be escaped with `\`.

A regular expression that should work is:

```
^/\*\s*\d*\s*\*/$
```

Explanation

```
^         # match only at the beginning of the line
/         # match a slash (/); the slash is a regular character in regex
\*        # match an asterisk (*); the asterisk needs to be escaped to represent itself
\s*       # match zero or more space characters (\s); these are whitespaces and tabs
\d*       # match zero or more digits (\d)
\s*       # match zero or more space characters
\*        # match '*'
/         # match '/'
$         # match at the end of the line (but not the end of line itself);
```

If you use this regex for search and the empty string for replace, the content of the comment lines is removed but the lines themselves are not removed (the line is determined by its end-of-line character).

In order to remove the comment lines altogether, add `\n` at the end of the above regex. `\n` matches the end-of-line character.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I finally manage to match with /* (.*)